# How export @ptkdev/webcomponent-instagram-widget in Angular module?

Tags: angular, widget, instagram, angular-compiler

I'm just trying to export '@ptkdev/webcomponent-instagram-widget' in Angular module, but I don't know how. I have tried everything.

Do you have an idea?

The component is working, but when I compile the project It shows an error because I'm using social component from another one.

This is my module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgxTwitterTimelineModule } from 'ngx-twitter-timeline';
import '@ptkdev/webcomponent-instagram-widget';
import { SocialComponent } from './social.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NbCardModule } from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [SocialComponent],
   imports: [
   CommonModule,
   NgxTwitterTimelineModule,
   NbCardModule,
   TranslateModule,
],
   exports: [SocialComponent],
})
export class SocialModule {}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: refer to this example: https://github.com/ptkdev-components/webcomponent-instagram-widget/blob/master/examples/angular/src/app/app.module.ts. and then you'll want to include `PtkdevInstagramWidgetWcComponent` in your declarations and in your exports